# What is the correct way to use moment.js locale in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, momentjs, locale

I'm following these links to change the locale of my datepicker but it still not working.

There are no console log error's when the page is loaded.

Links:

```
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#using-locales
https://github.com/moment/moment
```

My code:

gemfile

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'
```

application.js

```
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require moment/pt-br
```

dashboard.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
        locale: 'pt-br'
    });
});
```

html.erb file:

```
           <div class='col-md-6'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= label_tag :initial_date, 'Data Inicial' %>
                <div class='input-group date' id='initial_date'>
                  <%= text_field_tag(:initial_date, @filter&.initial_date, class: "form-control datetimepicker", id: "datetimepicker", autocomplete: "off") %>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: should it be `$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(...)` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using yarn if you are using a version of rails 5> 0, here you can see some useful links: 
http://nithinbekal.com/posts/yarn-rails/ 
`yarn add moment`
https://momentjs.com/